# terminal board for a game

Tags: python

I'm making a game as a university project. I want to make a board so that the players can move.

The board should look like this, this one is made with **colored**, but it won't work for my purpose since movements and players cannot be implemented.

```
import colored

nb_rows = 20
nb_cols = 20

to_display = ''
for row_id in range(nb_rows):
    for col_id in range(nb_cols):
            if (row_id + col_id) % 2 == 0:
                to_display += colored.bg('yellow') + colored.fg('red')
            else:
                to_display += colored.bg('green') + colored.fg('blue')
                
            to_display += '  ' + colored.attr('reset')
    
    to_display += '\n'
    
print(to_display)
```

I didn't find anything helpful in their [documentation](https://blessed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I'm wondering if there is a way to do the same but with blessed instead.

Comment: Hi @Goetia, welcome to stack overflow! What is the result you want to achieve? I can't get it

Comment: Hi @LucasVazquez, I want to create a board game of 20×20 so that `team 1` can play versus `team 2` for example, I have to do it with `blessed` for I can have control over players' placements or movements.

Comment: consider it like a chessboard, where players can move in several directions based on their role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used `blessed` before, so I'll give you a partial solution.

First of all, you should to know there's various examples in their repo that you can use to learn more about this package. Here is one: https://github.com/jquast/blessed/blob/master/bin/worms.py

So, after mentioning that, I leave you with a code example that might help. I put some comments on it because I think they can be useful.

```py
from functools import partial

from blessed import Terminal

terminal = Terminal()


def create_board(number_of_pair_cells, even_color, odd_color):
    echo = partial(print, end="", flush=True)

    # The height and width values may vary depending on the font size
    # of your terminal.

    # Each value of `cell_height` represents one line.
    cell_height = 1

    # Each value of `cell_width` represents one space.
    # Two more spaces are added by `echo`.
    # In this case, the final computed value is 0 + 2 = 2.
    cell_width = 0

    for i in range(number_of_pair_cells):
        # This generates the intermittent color effect typical of a board.
        if i != 0:
            even_color, odd_color = odd_color, even_color

        # This print the board.
        # I recommend you to replace the `"\n"` and the `" "` with
        # other values to know how this package works.
        # You'll be surprised.
        # Also, I recommend you to replace the `terminal.normal`
        # (that resets the background color) to `terminal.red`,
        # to have more info about the terminal dimensions.
        echo(
            *(
                "\n",
                *(
                    even_color,
                    " " * cell_width,
                    odd_color,
                    " " * cell_width,
                ) * int(number_of_pair_cells / 2),
                terminal.normal,
            ) * cell_height,
        )


# The `on_yellow` value is a reference to a yellow background color.
# This is the same for `on_green`.
# If you want to print a red color over a blue background,
# you need to use `terminal.red` and `terminal.on_blue`.
create_board(20, terminal.on_yellow, terminal.on_green)
```

[image: result]

---

Just a final comment.
I mad this example to show you that it is possible to make a board using `blessed`, but you probably find a better way to do it, more adapted to your needs. For example, you may want to use `print` instead of `echo` and you may want more `for` loops instead of unpacking iterables with the `*` operator.